# Continuously listen to server response in JSON

Tags: android, json, push-notification

How do I make so that a client side is always listening to a server response and update notification inside the client app? The server response is in JSON format.

Let's say I have two tabs. One tab is a listview of Twitter feeds and the other one is the settings. When a user is in Settings tab, a new Twitter feed came in and will give a notification to the user and to the counter located at the tab.

I don't know what to look or search for in google as I have no idea on what keyword should I use. So, if you have any links/tutorials/SO answers regarding response listening, please do help me.

Comment: Have you followed tutorial here http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few options and I bet there are many others too:

- if it is your API, then ask your backend guys to implement Google Cloud Messaging https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
- in case of twitter, there is something called Streaming APIs https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/streaming
- in general, create a service that reads data from the API, that service could be woken up periodically by an alarm (https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), check for new data, and push it to local store and inform twitter feed tab that there is a new data, or just push the new data directly to twitter feed tab if you don't use local store

First two options seems to be better as you read data from the backend when there is a new data actually.